# How to dynamically add items into QHorizontal layout without affecting window size or other items in the layout?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I've got a horizontal layout that holds a toolbar of sorts that's used to search/filter a TableView. The user is supposed to choose a column and an operator from the first two comboboxes, enter a search phrase in the text field, then hit the Search button to filter the table. There's a "Reset" button that clears any added filters, then a horizontal spacer to separate this group of widgets from the "Plot" button on the right.

It looks like this

[image]

All size policies for the widgets are set to "Minimum" except for the text field (Expanding) and the horizontal spacer (ignored).

I'd like to add a QLabel to the right of the "Reset" button that summarizes the filter that was just added, like this.

[image]

The problem is, my horizontal spacer won't shrink to allow the QLabel to take up space, so the entire window resizes. This is an issue because I've implemented "stacking" filters and would like to show the user every filter that's been added to the table.

Ideally, as more and more filters are added, I'd like the QLabels to shrink the horizontal spacer until it's effectively gone, then have them shrink themselves uniformly to fit the space between the "Reset" button and the "Plot" button. I never want the QLabels to affect the overall window size at all.

I've tried to set the horizontal spacer's size policy to ignored, minimum, and maximum, and it didn't affect anything i.e. as QLabels were added the entire window grew to fit them in. I've also tried taking the horizontal spacer out of the layout, inserting the QLabel, and then adding the spacer back in to "refresh" the horizontal layout (as suggested in [this](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/9281-Dynamically-resize-spacing) forum post).

**exampleUI.py (auto-generated using pyuic5):**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'example.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.12.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1538, 843)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.splitter_2 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter_2.setObjectName("splitter_2")
        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(self.splitter_2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(5)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.treeWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.treeWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.splitter_2)
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter.setObjectName("splitter")
        self.Widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.splitter)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(4)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.Widget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.Widget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.Widget.setObjectName("Widget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.splitter)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(2)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tabWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tabWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.columnComboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.columnComboBox_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.columnComboBox_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.columnComboBox_2.setObjectName("columnComboBox_2")
        self.columnComboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.columnComboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.columnComboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.columnComboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.columnComboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.columnComboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.columnComboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.columnComboBox_2)
        self.operatorComboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.operatorComboBox_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.operatorComboBox_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.operatorComboBox_2.setObjectName("operatorComboBox_2")
        self.operatorComboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.operatorComboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.operatorComboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.operatorComboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.operatorComboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.operatorComboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.operatorComboBox_2)
        self.FilterBar_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(3)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.FilterBar_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.FilterBar_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.FilterBar_2.setObjectName("FilterBar_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.FilterBar_2)
        self.SearchButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.SearchButton_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.SearchButton_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.SearchButton_2.setObjectName("SearchButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.SearchButton_2)
        self.resetFilterButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.resetFilterButton_2.setObjectName("resetFilterButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.resetFilterButton_2)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(800, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.tableView_2 = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.tab_2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(2)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tableView_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tableView_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tableView_2.setObjectName("tableView_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tableView_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.splitter_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1538, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Account"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Balance"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.treeWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Cash"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Credit"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(2).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Investments"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(3).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Loans"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(4).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Property"))
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.columnComboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Column:"))
        self.columnComboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Date"))
        self.columnComboBox_2.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Merchant"))
        self.columnComboBox_2.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Category"))
        self.columnComboBox_2.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Amount"))
        self.columnComboBox_2.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "Account"))
        self.columnComboBox_2.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "F.I."))
        self.operatorComboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "="))
        self.operatorComboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "<"))
        self.operatorComboBox_2.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", ">"))
        self.operatorComboBox_2.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "<="))
        self.operatorComboBox_2.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", ">="))
        self.operatorComboBox_2.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "NOT"))
        self.FilterBar_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Filter transactions..."))
        self.SearchButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Search"))
        self.resetFilterButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Reset"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Plot"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Transactions"))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**exampleApp.py (Application Class:)**

```py
from exampleUI import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSizePolicy
import sys

class exampleApp:

    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize QtWidgets
        self.MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

        # Initialize UI objects
        self.MainWindowUi = Ui_MainWindow()

        # Plug QtWidget object into setupUi method of UI object
        self.MainWindowUi.setupUi(self.MainWindow)

        self.MainWindow.show()

        self.MainWindowUi.SearchButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.add_filter(
            self.MainWindowUi.columnComboBox_2.currentText(), self.MainWindowUi.operatorComboBox_2.currentText(),
            self.MainWindowUi.FilterBar_2.text()))

    def add_filter(self, column, operator, phrase):
        filter_string = "{} {} {}".format(column, operator, phrase)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(filter_string)
        label.setToolTip(filter_string)
        label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Maximum, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.MainWindowUi.horizontalLayout_2.insertWidget(5, label, 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = exampleApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**example.ui**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1538</width>
    <height>843</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_5">
    <item>
     <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter_2">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="QTreeWidget" name="treeWidget">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Preferred">
         <horstretch>5</horstretch>
         <verstretch>1</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <column>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Account</string>
        </property>
       </column>
       <column>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Balance</string>
        </property>
       </column>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Cash</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Credit</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Investments</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Loans</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Property</string>
        </property>
       </item>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter">
       <property name="orientation">
        <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
       </property>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="Widget" native="true">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Expanding">
          <horstretch>1</horstretch>
          <verstretch>4</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Preferred">
          <horstretch>2</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="currentIndex">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
         <attribute name="title">
          <string>Transactions</string>
         </attribute>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
          <item>
           <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
            <item>
             <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
              <item>
               <widget class="QComboBox" name="columnComboBox_2">
                <property name="sizePolicy">
                 <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Fixed">
                  <horstretch>1</horstretch>
                  <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                 </sizepolicy>
                </property>
                <item>
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>Column:</string>
                 </property>
                </item>
                <item>
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>Date</string>
                 </property>
                </item>
                <item>
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>Merchant</string>
                 </property>
                </item>
                <item>
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>Category</string>
                 </property>
                </item>
                <item>
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>Amount</string>
                 </property>
                </item>
                <item>
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>Account</string>
                 </property>
                </item>
                <item>
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>F.I.</string>
                 </property>
                </item>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QComboBox" name="operatorComboBox_2">
                <property name="sizePolicy">
                 <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Fixed">
                  <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                  <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                 </sizepolicy>
                </property>
                <item>
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>=</string>
                 </property>
                </item>
                <item>
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>&lt;</string>
                 </property>
                </item>
                <item>
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>&gt;</string>
                 </property>
                </item>
                <item>
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>&lt;=</string>
                 </property>
                </item>
                <item>
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>&gt;=</string>
                 </property>
                </item>
                <item>
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>NOT</string>
                 </property>
                </item>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QLineEdit" name="FilterBar_2">
                <property name="sizePolicy">
                 <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
                  <horstretch>3</horstretch>
                  <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                 </sizepolicy>
                </property>
                <property name="placeholderText">
                 <string>Filter transactions...</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="SearchButton_2">
                <property name="sizePolicy">
                 <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Fixed">
                  <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                  <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                 </sizepolicy>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>Search</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="resetFilterButton_2">
                <property name="text">
                 <string>Reset</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
                <property name="orientation">
                 <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
                </property>
                <property name="sizeType">
                 <enum>QSizePolicy::Ignored</enum>
                </property>
                <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
                 <size>
                  <width>800</width>
                  <height>20</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
               </spacer>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
                <property name="text">
                 <string>Plot</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QTableView" name="tableView_2">
              <property name="sizePolicy">
               <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Preferred">
                <horstretch>2</horstretch>
                <verstretch>0</verstretch>
               </sizepolicy>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </widget>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1538</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Apologies for the lengthy UI file, but I felt it was important to capture all of the nested layout interactions to ensure my situation was understood. The exampleApp.py is minimalized to focus only on this issue.

Running exampleApp.py, then entering something into the text field and choosing a couple options from the comboboxes, then pressing the "Search" button multiple times will insert a couple labels into the horizontal layout and demonstrate my issue.

Anyone got any ideas as to how I can accomplish this?

Comment: provide  a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for the suggestion, I've added a minimal reproducible example that will demonstrate my issue.

Comment: share the .ui please

Comment: @eyllanesc Added a link to the .ui file to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are (as many of us have been) probably confused by the concept of `Minimum` of size policy. The documentation is not technically *wrong* (but it *is* confusing), you "only" need some attention and understanding to get it.

"`Minimum`" doesn't mean that the widget will use its size hint as a "minimum" size, but that the size hint «is minimal» ("*hint*" is the keyword: it's a "suggestion").
What you're looking for is actually `Maximum`: «the widget can be shrunk any amout» **but** «cannot be larger than the size provided by sizeHint()», which sets the `ShrinkFlag`. According to this, you'll probably end up with the `GrowFlag` too (which ensures that the widget can "grow" if necessary); this will bring you to using the `Preferred` sizePolicy, which is the default for most QWidgets. Carefully read the [QSizePolicy documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html), and do some tests by yourself to better understand it; it takes some time and a lot of attention, but it's worth it.

So, long story short: don't set a `Minimum` sizePolicy (unless really required) for **any** widget. Keep the default `Preferred` policy instead, and use `Expanding` for any other widgets that need to "consume" all the available space if they don't have it set as the default size policy.
In your specific case (at least, based on your question), it might be sufficient to reset the default policy of `tabWidget`, which is `Expanded` for both direction (but I'd suggest you to "undo" the widget property instead of manually setting it).